# Left Outer join and an additional where clause

Tags: sql, join

I have a join on two tables defined as a left outer join so that all records are returned from the left hand table even if they don't have a record in the right hand table. However I also need to include a where clause on a field from the right-hand table, but.... I still want a row from the left-hand table to be returned for each record in the left-hand table even if the condition in the where clause isn't met. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, put the condition (called a predicate) in the join conditions

```
   Select [stuff]
   From TableA a
       Left Join TableB b
           On b.Pk = a.Pk
               -- [Put your condition here, like this]
               And b.Column = somevalue
```

The reason this works is because the query processor applies conditions in a where clause *after* all joins are completed, and the final result set has been constructed. So, at that point, a column from the a table on the outer side of a join that has null in a a column you have established a predicate on will be excluded.

Predicates in a join clause are applied *before* the two result sets are "joined". At this point all the rows on both sides of the join are still there, so the predicate is effective.

Answer (score 12):

You just need to put the predicate into the `JOIN` condition. Putting it into the `WHERE` clause would effectively convert your query to an inner join.

For Example:

```
...
From a
Left Join b on a.id = b.id and b.condition = 'x'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x.fieldA, y.fieldB
FROM x
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select fieldb, fieldc from Y where condition = some_condition)
ON x.fieldc = y.fieldc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
WHERE (right_table.column=value OR right_table.column IS NULL)
```

This will return all rows from table 1 and table 2, but only where table 1 does not have a corresponding row in table 2 or the corresponding row in table 2 matches your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
  from table1 t1 
  left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 where t1.some_field = nvl(t2.some_field, t1.some_field)
```

**UPD:** errr... no. this way:

```
select * 
  from table1 t1 
  left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 where some_required_value = nvl(t2.some_field, some_required_value)
```

`nvl` is an Oracle syntax which replaces first argument with second in case it is `null` (which is common for outer joins). You can use `ifnull` or `coalesce` for other databases.

Thus, you compare `t2.some_field` with your search criteria if it has met join predicate, but if it has not, then you just return row from `table1`, because `some_required_value` compared to itself will always be true (unless it is `null`, however - `null = null` yields `null`, neither `true` not `false`.