# Filtering joined data

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a model with several entities.
Most important are Transportevent and Transporteventtype that are connected by association Transportstatus.
Therefore, Transportstatus contains foreign keys to those two tables.

In my query, I am trying to filter Transportstatustype id values. My query is inside a Transportevent repository, and $this->getAlias() returns "transportevent".

```
public function findAllDispatchedEvents($limit)
    {

        $transportstatusAlias = "ts";
        $transporteventtypeAlias = "tet";
        $transportstatustypeAlias = "tst";
        $crewAlias = "c";

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->getAlias());

        $qb->leftJoin($this->getAlias() . '.crew', $crewAlias)
            ->leftJoin($this->getAlias() . '.transporteventtype', $transporteventtypeAlias)
            ->leftJoin($this->getAlias() . '.transportstatuses', $transportstatusAlias)
            ->leftJoin($transportstatusAlias . '.transportstatustype', $transportstatustypeAlias)
            ->where($this->getAlias() . ".transporteventtype <> 3")
            ->andWhere($crewAlias . ".crewid IS NOT NULL")
            ->andWhere($transportstatustypeAlias . ".tstypeid NOT IN (10, 15, 17)")
            ->orderBy($this->getAlias() . ".actualstart", "DESC")
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

However, I'm not getting what I need. It seems that it's not possible to perform where clause over another table in a join.

Or am I doing something wrong?

As you can see, I need these results by certain conditions, where tstypeid is not in array (10, 15, 17). But I'm getting those values as well anyway.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer join and an additional where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677246/left-outer-join-and-an-additional-where-clause)