# LEFT JOIN to take all rows from left table irrespective of join condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do a left join such that I get all rows from left table even when the join condition is not true for those rows.

Example: Below Aid = Bid but Table B has only 3 ids

[image]

The Query that I am using gives only rows where the join condition is true. Is there a way to get all rows from left table even when the Join condition is not true?

My Query:

```
SELECT Table1.Aid,
       Table2.Bid,
       Table2.Issueid
  FROM Table1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Aid = Table2.Bid;

 WHERE Table2.Issueid IN (
    'a',
    'b'
)
```

Comment: Is that `where` clause part of the same query? There is a semicolon before it. If by the 'left' table you mean Table2 (on the right in your screenshot), your `where` clause specifies that you only want rows where Table2.Issueid is 'a' or 'b', so the rows where Table2.Issueid is null will be excluded.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. PS That is what you are getting & you are removing rows after via the where. If you don't want that, explain exactly what rows you do want. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer join and an additional where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677246/left-outer-join-and-an-additional-where-clause)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move your `WHERE` to your `ON` (join predicate):

```
SELECT Table1.Aid, Table2.Bid, Table2.IssueId
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Aid = Table2.Bid
   AND Table2.IssueId IN ('a','b');
```

A `WHERE` that filters on the right side table essentially makes your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  It filters out the `NULL` rows.

Keep in mind, this will now return `NULL` for the `Table2.Bid = 3` row, since it doesn't meet the `Table2.IssueId IN ('a','b')` condition.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added a Where clause, I think my where clause is causing this issue as its turning my JOin into a inner join. Is there a work arround this?

Comment: @Programmermid Almost always the solution is to move the `WHERE` to the join predicate with `AND`.  In your case you would get the expected results by leaving that part out all together, but I suspect in your real query you will want to move the `WHERE` to the `ON`.

Comment: You don't know what the query should be, eg that the where condition should be anded into the join on, so it is wrong to say that @Programmermid should do that--because they do not clearly say what they want--only that they want all left table rows & their query is wrong.

Comment: @philipxy OP expected their query to retain the all the left table rows because they are using `LEFT JOIN`, and asked why it isn't.  The answer is 100% because of the `WHERE` clause filter on the right table.  Moving the `WHERE` condition to `ON` is the correct (albeit general) solution to give until they say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised your query runs.  You should have an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT Table1.Aid, Table2.Bid, Table2.IssueId
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2
     ON Table1.Aid = Table2.Bid;
```

For the revised query, you still need to move the condition into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT Table1.Aid, Table2.Bid, Table2.IssueId
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2
     ON Table1.Aid = Table2.Bid AND Table2.IssueId IN ('a','b');
```

Comment: This query will only give three rows instead of expected five.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff -  You left out the predicate on the join

Comment: @Dan . . . I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - In your original answer, you left off the `AND Table2.IssueId IN ('a','b')`, which you've now corrected.

Comment: @Dan . . . I would call that a filtering condition, not a predicate on the `join`.  In any case, that wasn't actually in the question when I answered it (although I've updated the answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677246/left-outer-join-and-an-additional-where-clause

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454867/difference-between-filtering-queries-in-join-and-where

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `left outer join` in this situation without the `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT Table1.Aid, Table2.Bid, Table2.IssueId
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Aid = Table2.Bid 
                       AND Table2.IssueId IN ('a','b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired result the common answer of

```
  ON Table1.Aid = Table2.Bid 
  AND Table2.IssueId IN ('a','b')
```

won't give you the results you want. Specifically row 3 will be

```
3, null, null
```

not

```
3, 3, null
```

If that is what you actually want you'd get that simply by doing the left join without any where clause at all.